# Oracle SQL statement to find the row with input time stamp between two timestamp columns

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have a table in Oracle DB

```
|SHIFT|     START_TIME (TIMESTAMP)     |      END_TIME (TIMESTAMP)      |
|  2  |  01-AUG-15 11.00.00.000000 PM  |  02-AUG-15 08.00.00.000000 AM  |
|  4  |  01-AUG-15 07.00.00.000000 AM  |  01-AUG-15 04.00.00.000000 PM  | 
|  3  |  01-AUG-15 02.00.00.000000 AM  |  01-AUG-15 11.00.00.000000 AM  | 
|  1  |  01-AUG-15 02.00.00.000000 PM  |  01-AUG-15 11.00.00.000000 PM  | 
|  5  |  01-AUG-15 08.30.00.000000 AM  |  01-AUG-15 05.30.00.000000 PM  |
```

I want those row(s) to be returned which correspond to a particular timestamp.
Running the following query works:

```
select shift, 
  cast(start_time as time), 
  cast(end_time as time)
from mytable 
where cast('12.00.00.000000 PM' as time) 
  between cast(start_time as time) and
  cast(end_time as time);
```

BUT, the same query does not work for cast('12.00.00.000000 **AM**' as time)
i.e. the following query does not work. It returns 0 rows. What am I doing wrong?

```
select shift, 
  cast(start_time as time), 
  cast(end_time as time)
from mytable 
where cast('12.00.00.000000 AM' as time) 
  between cast(start_time as time) and
  cast(end_time as time);
```

I even tried with the match between start_time and the start_time + 9hours but get the same behavior.

```
select shift,
cast(start_time as time), 
cast((start_time + numtodsinterval(9,'HOUR')) as time) 
from ata_ipd_web_shifts where cast('12.00.00.000000 PM' as time) 
BETWEEN  cast(start_time as time) AND 
cast((start_time + numtodsinterval(9,'HOUR')) as time);
```

**So what is the issue here and what is the best way to extract the desired row(s)?**

Comment: The issue is that your time span goes over more than one day but you are only comparing times of day.  you need to do do a different comparison if your span covers more than one day.

Comment: I tried to keep it the same day but doesn't work.
Basically I just need to compare the times.
How to do this comparison then? Would appreciate any help; I am not that good with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the time of day you want to check for an INTERVAL and add it to both the start date of the shift and the end date of the shift.  Like this:

```
with d as ( SELECT 2 shift, to_timestamp('01-AUG-15 11.00.00.000000 PM') start_date, to_timestamp('02-AUG-15 08.00.00.000000 AM') end_date from dual
UNION ALL SELECT 4 shift, to_timestamp('01-AUG-15 07.00.00.000000 AM'), to_timestamp('01-AUG-15 04.00.00.000000 PM') from dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3 shift, to_timestamp('01-AUG-15 02.00.00.000000 AM'), to_timestamp('01-AUG-15 11.00.00.000000 AM') from dual
UNION ALL SELECT 1 shift, to_timestamp('01-AUG-15 02.00.00.000000 PM'), to_timestamp('01-AUG-15 11.00.00.000000 PM') from dual
UNION ALL SELECT 5 shift, to_timestamp('01-AUG-15 08.30.00.000000 AM'), to_timestamp('01-AUG-15 05.30.00.000000 PM') from dual
)
select * from d
where trunc(start_date)+TO_DSINTERVAL('0 09:00:00') between start_date and end_date
OR trunc(end_date)+TO_DSINTERVAL('0 09:00:00') between start_date and end_date
```

Note that the interval is 24-hour time, so midnight (that you used in your example) is 0 00:00:00.

Comment: This seems to be working! - I still have to wrap my head around it (my sql is rusty) Will try it for all scenarios and if any issue I will update this comment (or post a new one)

Comment: Hi Matthew.. is there a way to extract the strings passed to TO_DSINTERVAL from an existing timestamp.
Also, I have to pass the input from the timestamp column which will have different dates. Basically I just have to match it against the Time only.

Comment: Yes -- don't use TO_DSINTERVAL in that case.  Say the existing timestamp you have is `ts`.  Just make the where clause like `TRUNC(start_date)+(ts-trunc(ts))...`.  I'm not in front of a database right now, but that should work.

Comment: i took the short cut and split the row corresponding to shift 2 as:

   __   |SHIFT|   START_TIME (TIMESTAMP)      |      END_TIME (TIMESTAMP)      |
      |  2  |  01-AUG-15 11.00.00.000000 PM  |  01-AUG-15 11.59.59.000000 PM  |
     |  2  |  01-AUG-15 12.00.00.000000 AM  |  01-AUG-15 08.00.00.000000 AM  |

now my earlier query works fine. Thanks for your help though.. learned something and could use it in some other instance